# Setting delegates to "self" from a class method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, delegates

Say, I want to call a UIActionSheet from a helper class method. I want the helper class (not the object) to be the delegate of this actionsheet.
So I'm passing self to the delegate.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyTitle"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

My helper class implements the delegate methods as class methods and everything works fine.
But, I get a warning from the compiler that says, Incompatible pointer, sending Class when id is expected. I also tried [self class] and getting the same warning.

How can I avoid this warning?

Comment: In Objective-C, these are called "class methods", not "static methods". This may help you in future searches for assistance. :)

Comment: Thanks. I code switch Objective-C and C#. Can't avoid typos.

Comment: Thanks. I code switch Objective-C and C#. Can't avoid typos.

Comment: I'd just say "don't do this". It will confuse the hell out of anyone reading your code. Whenever I think it's a good idea to put lots of code into class methods, I find myself changing my mind a week later and creating a Singleton object. If someone else takes over your project, they will be posting here and asking how using a class as a delegate works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the delegate to `[self self]`.

Comment: I'm actually not completely sure, but since `self` is a pointer to the current object that will recive the message, masking a `Class` object as a `self` pointer somehow puts the compiler at ease. It's just a compiler thing, though; using `self` works fine, but the compiler warning will drive you crazy.

Comment: "Thanks. It works, but how does it work?" -> This is a solid sign of being a good programmer.

Answer (score 7):

You can get rid of the warning by casting self to type id.

```
[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyTitle"
                            delegate:(id<UIActionSheetDelegate>)self
                   cancelButtonTitle:nil
              destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

This will tell the compiler to treat the value as an `id` which conforms to the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol.

Comment: Anyway to do this in SWIFT?

Answer (score 0):

You won't quite the warning until you pass an object pointer to the method. It expects an `id`, where you give `Class` which is a `typedef struct objc_class *Class;`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding < UIActionSheetDelegate > at the class .h file interface declaration